# 特定の文字列を含むかを判定する関数の定義

Tags: python, pandas

下記のURLを格納したデータフレームに対し、特定の文字列に【完全一致する場合】【部分一致する場合】【NULLの場合】【それ以外】かを判定して、フラグを作成したいと考えています。元のデータフレームは、下記の通りです。

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'full_url': ['https://www.ABCDec.jp/shop/default.aspx', 'https://www.google.com/search', 'http://search.yahoo.co.jp/', 'https://www.ABCDec.jp/abcdSHOP/', 'https://www.google.co.jp/', 'None', 'https://www.google.com','https://www.google.co.jp/kfjdyes8&2222', 'https://www.google.com/search&ghsysusie?=sieueu3304', 'https://search.yahoo.com/smerudy&wkwjs8736?=dunx']})
```

このデータフレームに対して、
■'full_url' が下記に 【完全】一致　する場合、type＝'自然検索'
　urls_G = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.google.co.jp/', 'https://www.google.com/search']

■ 'full_url' が下記に 【部分】一致　する場合、type＝'自然検索'
　urls_Y = ['search.yahoo.co.jp', 'search.yahoo.com']

■'full_url' が 'None' の場合、type='入力なし'

■ 上記３パターン以外は、type ='その他'

とする、フラグ（新しい列「type」）を追加したいです。

作成したいデータフレーム内容は下記の通りです。

```
ans = pd.DataFrame({'full_url': ['https://www.ABCDec.jp/shop/default.aspx', 'https://www.google.com/search', 'http://search.yahoo.co.jp/', 'https://www.ABCDec.jp/abcdSHOP/', 'https://www.google.co.jp/', 'None', 'https://www.google.com','https://www.google.co.jp/kfjdyes8&2222', 'https://www.google.com/search&ghsysusie?=sieueu3304', 'https://search.yahoo.com/smerudy&wkwjs8736?=dunx'],
                   'type': ['その他', '自然検索', '自然検索', 'その他', '自然検索', '入力なし', '自然検索', 'その他', 'その他', '自然検索']})
```

考えたのは、下記コードなのですが、

```
urls_G = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.google.co.jp/', 'https://www.google.com/search']

urls_Y = ['search.yahoo.co.jp', 'search.yahoo.com']

def get_type(x):
    if x == 'None':
        return '入力なし'
    elif x in urls_G:             # 文字列の完全一致を判定
        return '自然検索'
    elif x.str.contains(urls_Y):  # 文字列の部分一致を判定
        return '自然検索'
    else:
        return 'その他'
        

df['type'] = df['full_url'].apply(get_type)
```

部分一致のところに下記のようなエラーが出てしまい躓いております。
＞'str' object has no attribute 'str'

このエラーへの対処法についてアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

```py
elif x.str.contains(urls_Y):  # 文字列の部分一致を判定
```

ではなく、

```py
elif urls_Y[0] in x or urls_Y[1] in x:  # 文字列の部分一致を判定
```

とかですかね。`in`演算子で文字列の中に特定の文字列が含まれているか判定できます。

> 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

この意味ですが、そもそも`x`が文字列型なので、`.str`という属性が無いということです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、リストの中の要素を指定する方法で対応できるのですね。ちなみに、今回の例では、含まれているか判定したい文字列（リストの要素）が２つですが、数が多い場合にすべてをelif 文内にすべてを記述すると見づらくなってしまうため、、たとえばfor文で判定したい文字列を回す（for y in urls_Y と y in x を使う？）等ができれば見やすくなると考えたのですが、上手い記述が分からず、、。よろしければこちらについてもお考えありましたらアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: `x`が`urls_Y`のいずれかの要素を含んでいるか判定する関数をつくって、それを`elif`で呼び出せばいいと思います。

Comment: たとえば elif (lambda x: True if x in urls_Y else False): のように、lambda等で定義するイメージでしょうか？？（このコード自体は、実行してみたところ、想定の結果は得られなかったため誤りですが、、）

Comment: 無理に`lambda`は使わなくてもいいと思いますが（もちろん使ってもいいです）。`def contains_Y(x):    for url in urls_Y:　・・・`みたいな関数を定義しておいて、`elif contains_Y(x):`くらいが分かりやすいのでは。

Comment: ありがとうございます。関数定義がイマイチ上手くできませんでした。。もうちょっと試してみます。。